# Remote File Access Client

Tags: java, file-transfer

I am looking to make a small application that allows a person to access files on their computer remotely. The files are served up by a daemon running on the machine and serving files to a web server on demand.

What sort of protocol is ideal for this kind of purpose? I don't want to use raw sockets (or FTP) to try and avoid firewall issues. Websockets can be a good alternative. Are there any other ways of doing it?

Is there something like this available for Java or any other language? I am looking for source code so closed source applications are out of question. I'd also like any other helpful pointers that get me started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

For java, you could simply read the file and Base64 encode it, then send the data as you go, with an End of file symbol at the end. Look up Buffered Output and Input streams, as well as sockets.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, use java.nio will be optimal solution. With help of java.nio package you can buffer the complete file and send it through network as per request wise. That means whenever some one requests a file. It wont directly download the complete file on remote client instead the application will load byte the content received from server. With the use of MappedByteBuffer and FileChannel class of java.nio package it can be easily implemented.

Below link should help you implement the solution.
http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be why reinvent the wheel. Just run a webserver on the invidual persons computer and configure it so that the files of interest are accessible via HTTP.

I'm not going to get into a long discussion on the security aspects of this but suffice it to say that setting this up could/will expose your internal computers to the big bad world so do a proper risk analysis and get management approval before you put it live. However if the risks are acceptable then I very much suggest using tried and tested Apache (and similar) rather than a home grown solution where possible.

Assuming that you have an internet facing webserver then you can configure Apache httpd mod_proxy to proxy through to the webserver running on the desktop. You can find the mod_proxy documentation on line but a bare minimum of configuration would be

```
ProxyRequests on
ProxyPass /computer/abc http://abc.internalnet/somewhere/
ProxyPassReverse /computer/abc http://abc.internalnet/somewhere/
```

Comment: But I don't want to run a full blown webserver on someone's machine mainly because of configuration pitfalls. Sure, whatever I run would resemble a webserver but I am looking for something lightweight and easily configurable. Kinda like windows live foldershare.